# Bullet on margin before running section

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I'm using KOMA-Script class.

For section titles I use the option:

\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=on]{section}

It works perfect. But Can I put a bullet ( before a section title? Ideally, it would be on the margin.

Comment: It would really be helpful, if you won't post only a code snippet (that is even not marked as code), but a minimal working example …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [How to print the heading numbers in the left margin](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NumbersAtLeftMargin/):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=on]{section}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbullet\hskip\marginparsep}\thesection\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]